# My tkinter window isn't showing everything it should

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I wrote this code and it makes the window I'm trying to create just fine:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

radValue = ""

def submit():
    rangeWin.destroy()

rangeWin = tk.Tk()
rangeWin.title("Range Calculator")
style = ThemedStyle(rangeWin)
style.theme_use("equilux")
bg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'background')
fg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground')
rangeWin.configure(bg=style.lookup('TLabel', 'background'))
upperFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)
lowerFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)
underFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)

frame1_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
frame1_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
frame2_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
frame2_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
frame3_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
frame3_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
frameList = [frame1_1, frame1_2, frame2_1, frame2_2, frame3_1, frame3_2]

upperFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
lowerFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
underFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=8)
frRow = 0
frCol = 0
for fr in frameList:
    fr.grid(row=frRow, column = frCol, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
    frCol += 1
    if frCol == 2:
        frCol = 0
        frRow += 1

lblName = ttk.Label(master=frame1_1, text="Name")
entName = ttk.Entry(master=frame1_1, width=10)
lblName.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
entName.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

lblHP = ttk.Label(master=frame1_2, text="HP")
entHP = ttk.Entry(master=frame1_2, width=8)
lblHP.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
entHP.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

lblCoord = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Coordinate")
entXCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
lblX = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="X")
entYCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
lblY = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Y")
entZCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
lblZ = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Z")
lblCoord.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
entXCoord.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
lblX.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
entYCoord.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="e")
lblY.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="e")
entZCoord.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="e")
lblZ.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="e")

lblHeight = ttk.Label(master=frame2_2, text="Height (Blocks)")
entHeight = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_2, width=8)
lblHeight.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
entHeight.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

frameSizeLeft = ttk.Frame(master=frame3_1)
frameSizeRight = ttk.Frame(master=frame3_1)
lblSize = ttk.Label(master=frame3_1, text="Size Class")
rbnTiny = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Tiny", variable= radValue, value="Tiny")
rbnSmall = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Small", variable= radValue, value="Small")
rbnMedium = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Medium", variable= radValue, value="Medium")
rbnLarge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Large", variable= radValue, value="Large")
rbnHuge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Huge", variable= radValue, value="Huge")
rbnGargantuan = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Gargantuan", variable= radValue, value="Gargantuan")
lblSize.grid(row=0, column=0)
frameSizeLeft.grid(row=1, column=0)
frameSizeRight.grid(row=1, column=1)
rbnTiny.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
rbnSmall.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
rbnMedium.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
rbnLarge.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
rbnHuge.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
rbnGargantuan.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

lblNotes = ttk.Label(master=lowerFrame, text="Notes")
txtNotes = tk.Text(master=lowerFrame)
lblNotes.grid(row=0, column=0)
txtNotes.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

btnSubmit = ttk.Button(master=underFrame, command=submit, text="Submit")
btnSubmit.grid(row=0, column=0)

rangeWin.mainloop()
```

Which looks like this:
[Pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cMVI.png)

The problem is that when I try to turn this code into a pop-up window, it doesn't show everything I defined. This is the main that calls the window:

```
from rangeCalculator import RangeCalculator
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("BattleTracker")
#window.geometry("200x200")
style = ThemedStyle(window)
style.theme_use("equilux")
bg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'background')
fg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground')
window.configure(bg=style.lookup('TLabel', 'background'))
newChar = RangeCalculator(window)

lblGreeting = ttk.Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the BattleTracker")
lblGreeting.grid(row=0, column=0)
btnOpen = ttk.Button(master=window, text="Input Stats")
btnOpen.bind("<Button>", lambda e: newChar.generateWindow())
btnOpen.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

And this is the program as the pop-up window:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle


class RangeCalculator:
    def __init__(self, win = None):
        self.win = win
        radValue = ""
        stats = {}

    def generateWindow(self):
        rangeWin = tk.Toplevel(master=self.win)
        rangeWin.title("Range Calculator")
        style = ThemedStyle(rangeWin)
        style.theme_use("equilux")
        bg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'background')
        fg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground')
        rangeWin.configure(bg=style.lookup('TLabel', 'background'))
        upperFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)
        lowerFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)
        underFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)

        frame1_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame1_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame2_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame2_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame3_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame3_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frameList = [frame1_1, frame1_2, frame2_1, frame2_2, frame3_1, frame3_2]

        upperFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        lowerFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        underFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=8)
        frRow = 0
        frCol = 0
        for fr in frameList:
            fr.grid(row=frRow, column = frCol, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
            frCol += 1
            if frCol == 2:
                frCol = 0
                frRow += 1

        lblName = ttk.Label(master=frame1_1, text="Name")
        entName = ttk.Entry(master=frame1_1, width=10)
        lblName.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entName.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

        lblHP = ttk.Label(master=frame1_2, text="HP")
        entHP = ttk.Entry(master=frame1_2, width=8)
        lblHP.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entHP.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

        lblCoord = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Coordinate")
        entXCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
        lblX = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="X")
        entYCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
        lblY = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Y")
        entZCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
        lblZ = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Z")
        lblCoord.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entXCoord.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
        lblX.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
        entYCoord.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="e")
        lblY.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="e")
        entZCoord.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="e")
        lblZ.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="e")

        lblHeight = ttk.Label(master=frame2_2, text="Height (Blocks)")
        entHeight = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_2, width=8)
        lblHeight.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entHeight.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

        frameSizeLeft = ttk.Frame(master=frame3_1)
        frameSizeRight = ttk.Frame(master=frame3_1)
        lblSize = ttk.Label(master=frame3_1, text="Size Class")
        rbnTiny = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Tiny", variable= radValue, value="Tiny")
        rbnSmall = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Small", variable= radValue, value="Small")
        rbnMedium = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Medium", variable= radValue, value="Medium")
        rbnLarge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Large", variable= radValue, value="Large")
        rbnHuge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Huge", variable= radValue, value="Huge")
        rbnGargantuan = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Gargantuan", variable= radValue, value="Gargantuan")
        lblSize.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frameSizeLeft.grid(row=1, column=0)
        frameSizeRight.grid(row=1, column=1)
        rbnTiny.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnSmall.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnMedium.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnLarge.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnHuge.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnGargantuan.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

        lblNotes = ttk.Label(master=lowerFrame, text="Notes")
        txtNotes = tk.Text(master=lowerFrame)
        lblNotes.grid(row=0, column=0)
        txtNotes.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

        btnSubmit = ttk.Button(master=underFrame, command=submit, text="Submit")
        btnSubmit.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def collectStats():
        stats = {
            "name": entName.get(),
            "hP": entHP.get(),
            "coordinate": [entXCoord.get(), entYCoord.get(), entZCoord.get()],
            "height": entHeight.get(),
            "size": radValue,
            "notes": txtNotes.get(1.0, tk.END)
        }
    
    def submit():
        rangeWin.destroy()
```

I've tried to find an answer to this all over the internet, but I haven't found anything. I'm still fairly new to Python and very new to tkinter.

Comment: You know that in your `collectStats` method you are missing the `self` argument and most variables there aren't defined.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure that one out. Every time I try to use self, I get a NameError.

Comment: When you define all of the widgets that you will later use, do this: `self.<name> = tk.<widget class>(...)` so basically change `entXCoord = ttk.Entry(...)` and `entXCoord.grid(...)` to `self.entXCoord = ttk.Entry(...)` and `self.entXCoord.grid(...)`. Btw this isn't going to fix the window problem

Comment: So you know how when you ask a question, the answer generally hits you right after you ask? Not using self is exactly what the problem was. Thank you for your help. You got me on track. I'll post the fixed code for anyone else who might run into this.

Comment: I didn't even think it would help with your original problem :D. I recommend you look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

After being shown how to use self correctly, I figured out what was wrong with the code. I'm putting the fixed code here for anyone else who might run into this.

Summarized Fix:

```
class RangeCalculator:
    ...
    def generateWindow(self):
        ...
        # The radValue needed self prepended to it.
        rbnTiny = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Tiny", variable= self.radValue, value="Tiny")
        rbnSmall = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Small", variable= self.radValue, value="Small")
        rbnMedium = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Medium", variable= self.radValue, value="Medium")
        rbnLarge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Large", variable= self.radValue, value="Large")
        rbnHuge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Huge", variable= self.radValue, value="Huge")
        rbnGargantuan = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Gargantuan", variable= self.radValue, value="Gargantuan")
        ...

    # This also needed self to be implemented.
    def collectStats(self):
        stats = {
            "name": self.entName.get(),
            "hP": self.entHP.get(),
            "coordinate": [self.entXCoord.get(), self.entYCoord.get(), self.entZCoord.get()],
            "height": self.entHeight.get(),
            "size": self.radValue,
            "notes": self.txtNotes.get(1.0, tk.END)
        }
```

If anyone would like to see the full program, here it is:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle


class RangeCalculator:
    def __init__(self, win = None):
        self.win = win
        self.radValue = ""
        self.stats = {}

    def generateWindow(self):
        rangeWin = tk.Toplevel(master=self.win)
        rangeWin.title("Range Calculator")
        style = ThemedStyle(rangeWin)
        style.theme_use("equilux")
        bg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'background')
        fg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground')
        rangeWin.configure(bg=style.lookup('TLabel', 'background'))
        upperFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)
        lowerFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)
        underFrame = ttk.Frame(master=rangeWin)

        frame1_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame1_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame2_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame2_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame3_1 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frame3_2 = ttk.Frame(master=upperFrame)
        frameList = [frame1_1, frame1_2, frame2_1, frame2_2, frame3_1, frame3_2]

        upperFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        lowerFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        underFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=8)
        frRow = 0
        frCol = 0
        for fr in frameList:
            fr.grid(row=frRow, column = frCol, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
            frCol += 1
            if frCol == 2:
                frCol = 0
                frRow += 1

        lblName = ttk.Label(master=frame1_1, text="Name")
        entName = ttk.Entry(master=frame1_1, width=10)
        lblName.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entName.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

        lblHP = ttk.Label(master=frame1_2, text="HP")
        entHP = ttk.Entry(master=frame1_2, width=8)
        lblHP.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entHP.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

        lblCoord = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Coordinate")
        entXCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
        lblX = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="X")
        entYCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
        lblY = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Y")
        entZCoord = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_1, width=2)
        lblZ = ttk.Label(master=frame2_1, text="Z")
        lblCoord.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entXCoord.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
        lblX.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
        entYCoord.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="e")
        lblY.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="e")
        entZCoord.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="e")
        lblZ.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="e")

        lblHeight = ttk.Label(master=frame2_2, text="Height (Blocks)")
        entHeight = ttk.Entry(master=frame2_2, width=8)
        lblHeight.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        entHeight.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

        frameSizeLeft = ttk.Frame(master=frame3_1)
        frameSizeRight = ttk.Frame(master=frame3_1)
        lblSize = ttk.Label(master=frame3_1, text="Size Class")

        # This is what was causing the window to only show up to this point
        # The radValue needed self prepended to it

        rbnTiny = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Tiny", variable= self.radValue, value="Tiny")
        rbnSmall = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Small", variable= self.radValue, value="Small")
        rbnMedium = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Medium", variable= self.radValue, value="Medium")
        rbnLarge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Large", variable= self.radValue, value="Large")
        rbnHuge = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeLeft, text="Huge", variable= self.radValue, value="Huge")
        rbnGargantuan = ttk.Radiobutton(master=frameSizeRight, text="Gargantuan", variable= self.radValue, value="Gargantuan")
        lblSize.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frameSizeLeft.grid(row=1, column=0)
        frameSizeRight.grid(row=1, column=1)
        rbnTiny.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnSmall.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnMedium.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnLarge.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnHuge.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        rbnGargantuan.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

        lblNotes = ttk.Label(master=lowerFrame, text="Notes")
        txtNotes = tk.Text(master=lowerFrame)
        lblNotes.grid(row=0, column=0)
        txtNotes.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

        btnSubmit = ttk.Button(master=underFrame, command=self.submit, text="Submit")
        btnSubmit.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Passed in self
    def collectStats(self):
        stats = {
            "name": self.entName.get(),
            "hP": self.entHP.get(),
            "coordinate": [self.entXCoord.get(), self.entYCoord.get(), self.entZCoord.get()],
            "height": self.entHeight.get(),
            "size": self.radValue,
            "notes": self.txtNotes.get(1.0, tk.END)
        }
    
    def submit():
        rangeWin.destroy()
```

Comment: Anyone having this problem wouldn't go through these many lines of code, just post a summary of the fix on top of the answer too.

Comment: No problem. Hope this helps.